# redeclaring class with dynamic namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to find a way to 'redeclare' a class using a closure. This is what i've got so far:

---

I have two simple classes which are identical, except for the namespace.
The namespace in test2.php is called "bla" and in new.php it's called "newname". Other than that, they are exactly the same.

```
namespace bla; //test2.php
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    { }

    public function bla()
    {
        echo '[A bla]';
    }
}
```

---

```
include ("new.php");
include ("test2.php");

use newname\A as A; // <-- dynamic

$a = new A();
$a->bla();
```

So this piece of code simply executes the method from the 'new.php' class instead of the class in 'test2.php'. This is actually what i need. But my problem is the last part of the code. Normally i would've used a namespace:

```
$a = new bla\A(); //Defined in 'test2.php'
$a->bla();
```

But because of the 'use as' statement i have to change that line to:

```
$a = new A(); //Defined in 'test2.php'
$a->bla();
```

So without a namespace infront of "A()".

Is there a way to keep the "bla\A()" namespace  (which is defined in test2.php), but that it still calls the method from "new.php" ??

Comment: Btw, not everything that has `use` in it is a closure. Closures are anonymous functions sharing variables from the outer scope. The `use` in this case would be called an alias or import or something along these lines :)

Comment: If the two classes are identical, then why do you need two classes?  DRY http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 1):

In this case , to call from each class , you should write =>

```
$bla = new bla/A("");
$bla->bla();        // to call from bla.php
```

and second class

```
$newname = new newname/A("");
$newname->something(); // to call from newname.php
```

and it will work , you do not need to overwork script with use keyword

also it is good practise to write classes in one file with namespaces like so =>

```
namespace bla{
     class A{
        // content
     }
}

namespace newname{
     class A{
        // content
     }
}
```

Comment: I know i could do it this way. But the reason i want to 'redeclare' the class is because i want to 'patch' the old bla\A() class. So i want to be able to call bla\A(), but it should execute the method from newname\A(). The technique is called monkey patching, so i know it's possible to do this. Just not sure how exactly.

Comment: sorry , but i can not get the question what you are going to do :(

Answer (score 1):

As it is said in comments, it is not a "closure" topic but only dynamic namespace topic.

I don't think you can use tue `use` keyword dynamically.
However, PHP is a dynamic language, you can chose dynamically which class you want with meta-programming:

```
$wantedClass = 'myWantedNamespace\MyWantedClass';
$instance    = new $wantedClass();
```